# Magento Payment Block Form

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I've created a payment method in magento 1.9.
Everything displays at admin and checkout.The minute i select the payment method radio button the block form does not appear.
Block/form/Accountpayment.php code below

```
//Template to the form which will be displayed at checkout
/**
 *
 */
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setTemplate('accountpayment/form/accountpayment.phtml');
}
```

Please advise.

Thanx

Comment: Have you created redirect.phtml file

Comment: i have a phtml file yes placed in the base /default/templates folder

Comment: if i need to merge into a theme how would i do that